# Secure parameters with powershell exec

Tags: c#, security, powershell

I have a Powershell app that retrieves some secret data- then needs to execute a .NET exe (locally) passing that data. It appears that passing the data as a raw param could expose it to users on the machine, so I'm looking for a way to keep it secure.

Possible solutions-

1. Get the data directly from the C# app (possible, but not ideal)
2. Put the data in an EFS encrypted file and pass the file location
3. Encrypt the param with a shared key (something built into windows?)

Any tips/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about "some secret data"?

Comment: Is the user running this script?

Comment: Create a named pipe in PowerShell and read from it in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Please see this Microsoft Technet article:

[Working With Passwords and Secure Strings in Windows Powershell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx)

#### The gist of the above article:

Basic example of encrypting a string:

```
$PlainParam = "param you want to encrypt"
$SecureParam = $PlainParam | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Cmdlets to look into:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString
ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Comment: Seems right. Unfortunately I'm locked to PS2 for the moment, so I'm back at the EFS file. Thanks.